# Cortar texto proveniente de un input almacenado en una variable con javascript o jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy almacenando en una variable el `.text` de un `input`. Por ejemplo la variable texto:

`texto = "Esto-es un mensaje"`

Quiero guardar parte del contenido de ese texto en otra variable. Hasta donde esta el guion que guarde por ejemplo lo siguiente en otra variable.

`texto2 = "es un mensaje"`

Es importante mencionar que ese texto va a ser variable por lo que debe tomarse solo lo que este despues del guion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion split() para separar las palabras que necesites por ejemplo:

```js
$("#Dividir").click(function () {
     var InputInicial = $("#InputInicial").val();
     var Dividido = InputInicial.split('-');
     $("#ValorAntesDeGuion").val(Dividido[0]);
     $("#ValorDespuesDeGuion").val(Dividido[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"value="Esto-es un mensaje" id="InputInicial" />
<input type="text" id="ValorAntesDeGuion" />
<input type="text" id="ValorDespuesDeGuion" />
<button id="Dividir">dividir</button>
```

El numero de elementos del arreglo que genera  dicha función depende de el numero de guiones que tiene tu cadena.

[Aqui](http://www.example.com/) te dejo la documentación.